# Migrating from sqlite to mysql - SQLalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, pythonanywhere

I recently tried to migrate a flask site using a SQLite db connected to using SQLalchemy. I am migrating to Pythonanywhere and I want to change to a mySQl db. I used this code to connect to the db:

```
mysql+mysqldb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@hanchera1d.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com/news
```

obviously I replace USERNAME and PASSWORD with the necessary values. I get this error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1044, "Access denied for user 'USERNAME'@'%' to database 'news'")
>   (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

please help, I'm not sure what to do at this point.
Thank you

Comment: Did you make the accounts and database already in the databases tab on pythonanywhere? Also if you didn't know Pythonanywhere has a [forum](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/) which the owners of the site check daily so they might be able to help you better.

Comment: yeah, I did make the database and copied it directly from the database page. and ty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Been playing around with my own account on Pythonanywhere and figured it out. The database name is `username$dbname` so your connection string should be:

```
mysql+mysqldb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@hanchera1d.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com/USERNAME$news
```